# Django syntaxError when starting django project in virtualenv with python 3

Tags: python, django

A question [very similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42611593/how-to-solve-syntaxerror-on-autogenerated-manage-py) already exists, but it is regarding python2. [In another related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42611593/how-to-solve-syntaxerror-on-autogenerated-manage-py) the user did not activate their virtual environment. I did.

After I encountered this problem in a larger project, I tried and succeeded in replicating it on a brand new project.

In empty folder test-django, I ran the following:

```
virtualenv env
env/scripts/activate
pip install django
```

to make sure python had successfully installed django, I tried:

```
python
import django
```

No import error was raised, and the version of Python running was **Python 3.6.3** (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49)

so then I started the project...

```
django-admin startproject test
```

project test was indeed successfully created. I then ran:

```
cd test
./manage.py
```

and got

> File "test-django\test\manage.py", line 14
>       ) from exc
>            ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

The contents of manage.py are:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "phoenix2.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

when I remove "from exc", the ImportError is raised successfully-- but I shouldn't be getting an ImportError, running from within a virtual environment that has django installed.

I tried running (from Python within the command line)

```
 from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
```

and did not get an ImportError

the contents of sys.path within the virtual environment:

> ['', '\test-django\env\Scripts\python36.zip', '\test-django\env\DLLs', '\temp\test-django\env\lib', '\test-django\env\Scripts', 'c:\python36\Lib', 'c:\python36\DLLs', '\test-django\env', '\test-django\env\lib\site-packages']

running django-admin --version: 2.0.5

in case it is helpful, here's the general system python's path contents:

> ['', 'C:\Python36\python36.zip', 'C:\Python36\DLLs', 'C:\Python36\lib', 'C:\Python36', 'C:\Python36\lib\site-packages']

pip freeze within virtualenv:

> Django==2.0.5
>   pytz==2018.4

pip freeze in general python:

> appdirs==1.4.3 
>   lxml==4.0.0 
>   packaging==16.8 
>   pyparsing==2.2.0
>   six==1.10.0 
>   virtualenv==15.1.0

Comment: Can you post the whole exception traceback.. ?

Comment: what I posted was the entirety of the traceback given

Answer (score 1):

How about run `python3 manage.py` instead of `./manage.py`?

And I suggest use `pipenv` instead of virtualenv+pip.

Comment: I ran python -V, it's 3.6.3

Answer (score 0):

```
This is the simple way to start new django project:-
In terminal do following steps

$ mkvirtualenv <env_name>
$ workon <env_name>
$ pip install django
$ django-admin startproject <project_name>
$ cd <project_name>
$ ./manage.py migrate
$ ./manage.py runserver
open this in browser http://127.0.0.1:8000/
open the project in pychram and then do this 
click on file -> settings -> projects interpreter -> add local -> select <env_name> -> click bin -> click python3 or python2 -> apply -> OK
```