# No response to python3 manage.py runserver command

Tags: python, django, server

I have created my first django project by following a tutorial and I am trying to test it.

Command `python manage.py runserver` returned **"SyntaxError: invalid syntax."**

My Django version is (pip3 show django-command):

- Name: Django
- Version: 2.1.5
- Summary: A high-level Python Web framework that encourages rapid
  development and clean, pragmatic design.
- Home-page: https://www.djangoproject.com/
- Author: Django Software Foundation
- Author-email: foundation@djangoproject.com
- License: BSD
- Location: /home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
- Requires: pytz

I found a similar problem/question [How to solve SyntaxError on autogenerated manage.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42611593/how-to-solve-syntaxerror-on-autogenerated-manage-py) and run python3 manage.py runserver command as suggested in the answers.

It gave me absolutely no response. The server is not running.
Terminal just skipped into new row.
[screenshot of the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vp9iV.png)

Can anyone help jme run my project on the server?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. There are insufficient details here for a reader to understand how you have made your server. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure. But you may can try

```
python manage.py runserver
python2 manage.py runserver
or python3 manage.py runserver
```

or more specifically

```
python3.6 manage.py runserver
```

depend on how you install your django.